# Glitch on profile page with dropdowns

Tags: bug, design

The next privilege button on the profile page shows through the three drop-downs on the top.

[image]

I tend to start my browsing at this page then check my inbox so I see it every visit.

Chrome&Firefox

Comment: I wonder if this is related to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17325/518562)?

Comment: This exact same thing just happened to me. Someone broke something!

Comment: The new top-bar design fixes this issue. So I doubt this will get fixed with the current top bar, not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Depends if the new top bar is just days away, or if it's still weeks or months away I guess.