# Achievements rep indicator glitching

Tags: support, bug

The rep indicator lit up saying I gained 141 points, but I only gained 4. This has happened twice in the past 10 minutes.

See the below screenshot...

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301418/inbox-shows-new-rep-earnings-which-arent-when-hopping-to-a-different-site